# substitution of variables for math equations

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm going to ask a seemingly silly question.

A simple example:
 Suppose we know that when $(x,y) \in A$, which is a subset of $R^{2}$, then $x+y=c$, where c is a constant. We also know that $(3,4) \in A$, and we want to find the value of c.

Without much thinking, we would just replace $x$ with 3 and $y$ with 4 in the equation and solve for the constant c.

My question is that why we do this? Why replacing $x$ with 3 and $y$ with 4 would cause the equation to hold?

I know this is about predicate logic and when some values satisfy the premise they would also satisfy the followed statement. But why 'satisfying a statement' equals to 'replacing variables with values and the statement becomes true'?

This has been a simple logic for me all along but I recently find it bothering.

Comment: Well, it's a strange statement.  What is $A$?  Is it meant to be a subset of the reals?  But if it has two or more elements then your equality can't hold for both.  Same for $B$.  So then $A$, $B$ are just single element sets?  Seems an odd way to phrase things...

Comment: I could change the equation into a much complicated polynomial having a lot of constant parameters, then $A$ and $B$ can be large sets, and when solving for those parameters we would still do the same things.

Comment: As lulu said it is necessary to know if the elements of $A$ and $B$ are reals or other stuff, in the second case you would need to define your operation $+$ over some set containing $A$ and $B$. But ic they are reals the equality holds because of the properties of addition (for instance injectivity when one of the entries is fixed)

Comment: I will rephrase the problem.

Comment: Well...it's your example.  To the extent I understand what you are asking (maybe I don't understand it at all), then...yes.  If I say, "given any pair of elements $x\in A$ , $y\in $B$ then some property $P(x,y)$ holds" it follows that you can actually choose elements from those sets and rely on the property.

Comment: I guess my question is "why 'satisfying a statement' equals to 'replacing variables with values and the statement becomes true' "?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. If it is true that whenever $(x,y) \in A$ that $P(x,y)$ is true, then when you are given that $(3,4) \in A$, then you know that $P(3,4)$ is true.

Comment: I understand P(3,4) should be true based on a predicate's property, but why?

Comment: Or why a predicate would have this property?

Comment: If $c$ is not a fixed value, the equation is not a "predicate"; what we have is a *function* : $+ : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$. For any $x,y \in \mathbb R$ the function $+$ gives us a value : $+(x,y)$. Example : $+(3,4)=7$. Nothing change if we consider a subset $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ as domain for the "inputs" $x,y$.

Comment: If we have a "real" equation, like e.g. $x+y=2$, from the point of view of predicate logic this is : $\exists x \ \exists y (x+y=2)$. It is a *sentence* (a closed formula) and it is *true* in $\mathbb R$ because the predicate $x+y=2$ is satisfied by e.g. $(1,1)$.